# Is it possible to access a variable in another method within the same class?

Tags: python-2.7

I'd like to know if it is possible for access the variable defined in `function1` into `function2` within the same `MainWindow` class as in the following code? 
How about accessing a variable in another method but from a different class?

```
import os

class MainWindow():

    def __init__(self, name):

        self.name = name

    def function1(self):

        if self.work != []:
             self.variable = self.existing_work.variable

    def function2(self):

        if not os.path.isdir(self.variable):

            return False

        else:

          return True
```

Comment: Have you tried? Did you get an error?

Comment: No, I haven't tried because this is a small part of a much larger code. It's not possible to run right now. I'd like to know if it's possible in theory.

Comment: Your example code is practically already runnable. Why not go the extra mile and run it?

Answer (score 0):

Any attribute you create, as in `self.variable`, is accessible from any other method in the same way that `self.name` is provided that you create it before attempting to access it.

In your example, `function1` must run before `function2` else it will fail.

Comment: Thanks!  And how about accessing a variable in another method but from a different class? Is it the same theory?

Comment: Any `self.variable`s are instance variables so must be accessed through the instance.  I recommend creating a dummy script to play around with or using a python shell to help you better understand how to access class and instance variables.